# XSL - Working with call-template with multiple source XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a single XSL file that I am using to transform/build an XML file from multiple sources, where several elements and attributes need to be updated on the fly.  I'm wondering whether this scenario should work in a `<call-template/>` block with a parameter.

When I pass an external file reference through as a parameter, the "Code" attribute under `EXPORT/Top/Shapes/Shape/Material` is not updated:

```
<xsl:template match="Shapes">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('..\TempReportData\TextXML_Output.xml')/Job/Benchtops/Benchtop">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('..\DesignMaster\EmptyShapeElement.xml')" />
            <xsl:call-template name="updateMaterial">
                <xsl:with-param name="mCode" select="./Top_number"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="updateMaterial" match="@Code[parent::Material]">
<xsl:param name="mCode"/>
<xsl:attribute name="Code">
    <xsl:value-of select="$mCode">
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the desired outcome where the Code attribute inside the `<Material></Material>` element is updated from the external file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EXPORT>
<Top Id="1" Code="B90512">
<Shapes>
<!--Shape-->
<Shape Id="1" Code="Penisola">
<!--Material-->
<Material Code="TOP(2257)"></Material>
</Shape>
<!--Shape-->
<Shape Id="1" Code="Penisola">
<!--Material-->
<Material Code="TOP(2260)"></Material>
</Shape>
</Shapes>
</Top>
</EXPORT>
```

The XML file TextXML_Output.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Job>
<Job_Number>B90512</Job_Number>
<Job_Address>2nd Floor/ 28-32 Albert Road   VIC 3205</Job_Address>
<Benchtops>
<Benchtop>
<Top_number>TOP(2257)</Top_number>
</Benchtop>
<Benchtop>
<Top_number>TOP(2260)</Top_number>
</Benchtop>
</Benchtops>
</Job>
```

I get a little lost when working with multiple templates and files, but it seems to me that this should work fine, but it doesn't.

Comment: Where is the element `Top_number`?  Is it in `TextXML_Output.xml`, or rather in `EmptyShapeElement.xml`?

Comment: `Top_number` is in `TextXML_Output.xml`

Comment: Consider to cut all needed documents to a minimum to present the problem and allowing us to reproduce it, but then post all those documents. We can't debug code you don't show and we need to see the input documents.

Comment: Edited the questions to try and make it a little clearer.

Comment: It would be less confusing if your input file were called something other than XMLOutput.xml. Not surprising you get lost.

Comment: What is in EmptyShapeElement.xml? You can't expect us to guess. Does removing the apply-templates on this document change anything? Your named template is creating an attribute node, and we can't see what element that attribute is being attached to.

Comment: The EmptyShapeElement.xml file contains everything within the `<Shapes></Shapes>` element as shown in the desired output.  It is added to the original file which only contains the `<EXPORT>` and `<Top>` elements, so the `<Material>` element needs to be added before the `"Code"` attribute can be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with your `Shapes` matching template

```
<xsl:template match="Shapes">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('..\TempReportData\TextXML_Output.xml')/Job/Benchtops/Benchtop">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('..\DesignMaster\EmptyShapeElement.xml')" />
            <xsl:call-template name="updateMaterial">
                <xsl:with-param name="mCode" select="./Top_number"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You start off by creating a `Shapes` element in the output. Then you iterate over all `Benchtop` elements in another document, and for each one you copy an "Empty Shape Xml" as a child of the `Shapes` element you have created. But then you call the `updateMaterial` template, which adds an attribute. This will actually try to create an attribute on the parent `Shapes` element you previously created, but according to the [W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes)...

> Adding an attribute to an element after children have been added to
>   it; implementations may either signal the error or ignore the
>   attribute.

So, in your case it looks like the XSLT processor is ignoring the attribute, rather than throwing the error.

But from looking at what you are trying to achieve, it looks like you want to add the attribute to a `Material` element which is part of the "EmptyShapeElement.xml" you are copying.

What you could do is change your identity template, which I assume your full XSLT is using, to carry around a `mCode` parameter....

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:param name="mCode"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="mCode" select="$mCode" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then pass the `Top_Number` value as this parameter when you select the "EmptyShapeElement.xml"

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$EmptyShapeElement">
  <xsl:with-param name="mCode" select="Top_number" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Finally, your existing template for the attribute does not need to be named now

```
<xsl:template match="Material/@Code">
    <xsl:param name="mCode"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Code">
        <xsl:value-of select="$mCode" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

(This is assuming the `Material` element in your "EmptyShapeElement.xml`does indeed have an existing`Code` attribute you want to replace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="TextXML_Output" select="document('..\TempReportData\TextXML_Output.xml')" />
    <xsl:variable name="EmptyShapeElement" select="document('..\DesignMaster\EmptyShapeElement.xml')" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:param name="mCode"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="mCode" select="$mCode" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Shapes">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="$TextXML_Output/Job/Benchtops/Benchtop">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$EmptyShapeElement">
                  <xsl:with-param name="mCode" select="Top_number" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Material/@Code">
        <xsl:param name="mCode"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="Code">
            <xsl:value-of select="$mCode" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim C.  This code is certainly cleaner, however when I run it, the `Code` attribute is still not updated correctly.  It is saved as `Code=""`.  To test, I placed some static text in the `<xsl:value-of select="$mCode" />` line, like `<xsl:value-of select="'Some static text'" />` and it placed the text in the attribute correctly, so the principal is correct, it is just not passing the value through the parameter.

Comment: @paularmy42 : What about a pipeline, where you create your 2nd level document, but pass it on to another xslt instance via unixy pipeline (`|`) to make the final changes you need? (Just a crude guess on my part!). Good luck to all.

Comment: @paularmy42 It's possible that in your actual XSLT you have other templates that take priority over the identity template, so you would need to pass around the parameter in that too.